# Imgur API won't remove image from album

Tags: python, google-app-engine, imgur

I'm using the Imgur API to create an album under a users account, and then add or remove images from that album.

I can authenticate successfully, create the album, and add images to the album without a problem.

When I go to remove an image from the album, I get this response:

```
{'success': True, 'data': True, 'status': 200}
```

However, the image remains in the album. As far as I can tell, I'm correctly sending the request using an HTTP delete.

The Imgur album page also seems to have gone a little screwy. After having attempted to remove and re-add the same image to the album a few times, the albums page of my account lists the album as having 3 images. But if I go into the actual album, it says it only has one image.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was mistakenly using the DELETE call wrong. I was including the ids I wanted to remove as parameters in the request, as if it was a POST request.

Instead I needed to include the ids in the URL like this:

```
https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{album}/remove_images/?ids={theid}
```

Comment: The new API documentation is INCORRECT (as of Jan 18th 2018). It specifies a POST request with the ids in the body of the request. That does not work (and in fact will add those images to the album instead of removing them, which is odd behavior and may be a bug). The above answer is the correct way to remove images from an album, at least for now.

Comment: @felwithe do u know how can I remove the image from album. the remove image from album api removeing all other images instead of the provided id